# How to choose the $k$ points that given a cost matrix with other points, give the minimum sum of distances

Tags: optimization

For two sets of $n$ dimensional points this is their distance matrix:

|  | $p_{11}$ | $p_{12}$ | $p_{13}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $p_{21}$ | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| $p_{22}$ | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| $p_{23}$ | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| $p_{24}$ | 2 | 1 | 8 |

How can I get the $n$ points of $p_{1i}$ that give the minimum sum of distances in the most efficient way possible.

So far best I could do was apply the Hungarian assignment algorithm in a loop for all possible teams (this takes $\binom{i}{n}$ loops though and is not very efficient)

The solution for n=2 would follow this procedure:
find the minimum sum of the minimum distances that each couple of p1,i gives for each row, for example:

$(p_{1,1}, p_{1,2}) = 1^{*}+2+2+1 = 6$

$(p_{1,2}, p_{1,3}) = 2+3+1+1 = 7$

$(p_{1,1}, p_{1,3}) = 1+2+1+2 = 6$

So the optimal couple would be either $(p_{1,1}, p_{1,2})$ or $(p_{1,1}, p_{1,3})$

explanation of the $1^{*}$: its the $min(d(p_{2,1},p_{1,1}), d(p_{2,1},p_{1,2}))=1$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 ah that's better, thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax (and Markdown tables, if applicable) next time.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: You are given a bipartite graph and want to choose $k$ points from the left ($p_{i,1}$) side to minimize the sum of distances from these $k$ points to all points on the right ($p_{2,j}$) side?

Comment: @RobPratt I want to choose the correct k points that compared to all other combinations of k points of the left minimize the sum of distances to the points on the right, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R=\{1,2,3,4\}$ be the left and right sides of the bipartite graph.  Let $c_{i,j}$ be the cost of assigning left node $i$ to right node $j$ (the transpose of your table above).  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether left node $i$ is assigned to right node $j$, and let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether left node $i$ is selected.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i \in L} \sum_{j \in R} c_{i,j} x_{i,j}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \in L} x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for $j\in R$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i \in L} y_i &= k \tag2 \\
x_{i,j} &\le y_i &&\text{for $i \in L$ and $j \in R$} \tag3 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one left node per right node.
Constraint $(2)$ selects exactly $k$ left nodes.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces the logical implication $x_{i,j} \implies y_i$.

Your first optimal solution above has $x_{1,1}=x_{1,2}=x_{1,3}=x_{2,4}=y_1=y_2=1$ and all other variables $0$.

Comment: that would give the k points that are most in the "middle", I'm looking for the group of k points whose sum of minimum distances from the other points is the minimum of all other sums of distances that are produced by other combinations of k points

Comment: I don't follow.  What is your desired optimal solution for your sample data?

Comment: I have edited the post, hope it helps

Comment: @Mario Yes, clear now.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I have no words to thank you enough! Brilliant solution!